# Android Listview Focus with child view as background

Tags: android, listview

In my app i'm setting background to each child views in listview.
So that listview default focus ( orange color ) is not focusing.

Is there any way to set both ( listview focus & child view background ) ?..

**Edit:**
This is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">;
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/img_focused" /> 

    <item android:state_focused="true" 
    android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/img_selected" /> 

    <item android:state_focused="false" 
    android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/img_selected" />

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_default" />
</selector>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try following states sort order:

```
<item android:drawable="@drawable/poster_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/poster_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
```

Comment: You can try following states sort order:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/poster_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/poster_focused" android:state_focused="true"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/poster_disabled" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/poster_normal"/>

</selector>

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you define the item background as StateListDrawable. In XML it's done with [selector](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Comment: Ognian, Thanks fro your reply...
I'm using selector only.. I'm getting image only in pressed state not in focus.. You have any idea  ?...

Comment: This is my code

<code>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
    android:state_pressed="false" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/img_focused" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
    android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/img_selected" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
    android:state_pressed="true" 
    android:drawable="@drawable/img_selected" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/img_default" />
</selector> 
</code>